# Slack messages do not reach Azure

Tags: azure, botframework, slack-api

So I have an issue to make the communication possible between Slack and BotFramework. I deploied once a bot on Slack to test the deployment and everything was working fine. I worked on another bot and when I try to deploy it there is no message reaching the bot on Azure.

Since I can not see errors on Azure or from Slack, I think my issue does not come from my code. What seems very strange is that I did not get any message from Slack telling me that the messages can not reach the bot and yet I can not see message reaching Azure.

I use this to install the bot on Slack https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-slack except that I did not suscribe to events which was working fine with my initial deployment.

I tried with a sample bot, I got the same issue. So I must be missing something about the configuration.

My bot is working fine with cortana and directline.

Comment: Do you see any requests incoming to the server?

Comment: I do not see any

Comment: Do your try to turn on application insight to trace and check if the requests hit the server? Beisdes, does your bot work as expected with other channels, such as webchat?

Comment: As I said, my bot works fine with the channels Cortana and DirectLine and it also works fine in the web chat. I do not see any request coming from Slack in Application Insight.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the configuration for Slack and then attempting to re-add the channel back? If not, can you try the process again and open up a Developer console in your browser when you start the process? This is so if you receive any error messages during the process you can get the .har file.

Comment: I have tried to re-add the channel multiple times and never got an error.

Comment: "except that I did not suscribe to events" - you need to subscribe to the events from the Slack app page "Events Subscription". This is how the Bot Connector Service gets event from Slack and send to your bot.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I'd try is to find out if the problem is on the Slack side or the Bot Service side.

To test out the Bot Service side:

- Have you tried running in the test chat?
- Or tried debugging the bot service on your local machine?

If it helps, I've written up a little tutorial on [how to debug a bot service](https://www.developerlabs.co/articles/2018/3/18/debug-your-bot-service).

Hope that helps!

Tim

Comment: My bot is working fine locally, on Cortana, using DirectLine and in the web chat. My message in Slack just do not hit Azure.